# Struts2 conditional check inside iterator

Tags: struts2, conditional-statements, iteration

I have a table in a jsp in which i am displaying data from a list, using the s:iterator tag.  The list is already sorted by description and I need to be able to display a row in the table above each group of descriptions.  For example (imagine this is a table):

Heading1-----
1 Heading1
2 Heading1
3 Heading1
Heading2-----
4 Heading2
5 Heading2
Heading3-----

What i want to do is iterate through the list and compare the current description with the previous description and if they are different, display the current description as a new row.

I tried a few different variations of this - which did not work:

```
<s:iterator value="myList" status="rowStatus">
<s:if test="{myList[%{#rowStatus.index}].description != myList[%{#rowStatus.index-1}].description}">
     <tr>
          <td colspan="7"><s:text name="description"/></td>
     </tr>
 </s:if>
```

I feel like i'm very close, but I just can't seem to figure out the proper syntax.  What am i missing here??

Thanks in advance!

*j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OGNL expression should be the entire `"test"` attribute:

```
<s:iterator value="myList" status="rowStatus">
  <s:if test="%{myList[#rowStatus.index].description != myList[#rowStatus.index-1].description}">
    ... etc ...
```

That said, it seems a lot of noise in the JSP; I'd consider something like this:

```
<s:iterator value="myList" status="rowStatus">
  <s:if test="%{#cur != description}">
      ... etc ...
  </s:if>
  <s:set var="cur" value="description"/>
</s:iterator>
```

There are other options, including setting a flag on the Java side.

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thank you so much.  I had so much trouble finding an example that was similar to my issue.  Is there any documentation you could point me to on OGNL?  I am not very knowledgeable in this  :)    Thanks again!!

Comment: @jacosta No problem :) There's two short intros on the S2 wiki ([here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html) and [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html). OGNL is now an Apache project and there's more available on [its website](http://commons.apache.org/ognl/).